# PHP Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: php, mysql

Появляется ошибка PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool в строке `$existence = selectOne ('vet_center.userss', ['email' => $email]);`с чем может быть связана?

```
$existence = selectOne ('vet_center.userss', ['email' => $email]);
if ($existence ['email'] === $email){
  $errMsg = "Пользователь с такой почтой уже зарегистрирован!";
} else{
  $pass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $post = [
  'username' => $login,
  'email' => $email,
  'password' => $pass,
  'admin' => $admin
  ];
```

Код для функции selectOne:

```
function selectOne($table,$params = []){
    global $pdo;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";

if(!empty($params)){
$i=0;
 foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
         if (!is_numeric($value)){
             $value = "'".$value."'";
         }
         if ($i === 0){
             $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key = $value";
         }else{
             $sql = $sql . " AND $key = $value";
         }
         $i++;
    }
}
$sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
$query = $pdo->prepare ($sql);
$query->execute();
dbCheckError($query);
return $query -> fetch();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ошибка не на этой строке

```
$existence = selectOne ('vet_center.userss', ['email' => $email]);
```

а на этой:

```
if ($existence ['email'] === $email){
```

Т.к в `$existence` в итоге лежит булево значение, т.к. `selectOne` вернул `false`

Comment: да, все верно ошибся, проблема в этой строке `if ($existence ['email'] === $email`

Comment: и еще такая же проблема с сессиями  `$user = selectOne ('vet_center.userss', ['id' => $id]);

      $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
      $_SESSION['login'] = $user['username'];
      $_SESSION['admin'] = $user['admin']; `

Comment: Ответ я уже дал час назад

Comment: окей, а как можно исправить, чтобы переменная $existence возвращала массив

Comment: Починить запрос selectOne. без понятия что у тебя там под капотом. может у тебя должно быть `users`, а не `userss`. А может `$email` пустой ......... А что внутри функции вообще не представляю, может там проблемы. Включи отладчик и пройдись там в коде, смотри что на каждой строчке куда передаётся и формируется. Включи отображение ошибок полное...........https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482